# Find exact opening and closing time in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, datetime-format

I hope you're all doing well.

I am using the following function to find the opening and closing times for a store:

```
  function timeBetween($sunrise, $sunset){ 
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
    $current_time = date('h:i a');
    $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $current_time);
    $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $sunrise);
    $date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $sunset);
    if ($date1 >= $date2 && $date1 < $date3){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

It is working fine, but the problem came when a user selects times from two different dates like 9am to 2am. If the format remains the same like 1 am to 11pm it works fine.

**Note:** I am just asking for the opening and closing time, not any date.

Can somebody help me to achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the client side you just need to ensure they're not able to send through times on different dates, isn't this just a data validation issue?

Comment: @EM-Creations nope, many shop remain open for next date like 11am to 1am. so its not  validation issue.

Comment: Then I think you also need to include the date as part of the date format, rather than just hourly times.

Comment: may be there is a way to achieve it without taking date ? can you please give it up vote to find the exact answer? Thanks

Comment: If you don't store or calculate the date for the next day and use that in your if statement it's never going to work because 2AM is always going to be before 9AM (because PHP at the moment doesn't know that the 2AM is actually for the day after), if that makes sense?

Comment: if you allow the times to potentially be on different dates, then how can you ever expect to understand which date each time relates to, if you don't include the date in the information provided? The computer cannot guess it, any more than you or I could guess when given the same information. If you want to allow this, then providing a date component with each time (or, at minimum a "next day" true/false flag on the end time)  is a basic requirement. I can't understand why you're even asking whether it would be possible without that. It's trivially obvious that it can't be done.

Comment: You _could_ make an assumption that if the end time is earlier than the start time, then the end time must really refer to the following day. But then that destroys the possibility of validating when the user has made a simple mistake (e.g. putting 10pm-10am might be a simple error, not an indication that the shop opens overnight). This is not really a better situation than what you have got now. To avoid uncertainly, extra information must be given.

Comment: @ADyson i am thinking same

Comment: but let's wait for more better answer :)

Comment: @ADyson: I had the same issue on a site of mine, and that is what I did.  Always expect the closing time to be after openning time.  So it it is smaller, I assume it is the next day.  I used a Javascript to warn the user of the fact, to avoid input errors.

Comment: @Nic interesting. Of course that can work, as I mentioned, but it requires you to assume the user did not make a simple human error in selecting an closing time which appears to be "earlier" than the opening time. IMO that's not an ideal situation because it leaves potential ambiguity. If it was me, I would add an extra tick-box which the user is required to tick in that situation, to show that they understand that they are specifying a "next-day" closing time, and not just getting confused (which users are, unfortunately, very prone to :-)).

Comment: @ADyson: thus the javascript I added.  Before using the user's input, I would let him know in a field that is hidden until the user does that kind of input.  Something to let him know that I will assume his input is on the next day.  This gives him the chance to modify his selection before moving on.

Comment: Ok I got you, sorry. Yeah that seems a reasonable approach, really.